# How can I moderate how much data I get from a file stream in python?

Tags: python, stream, xmodem

I've got an embedded system I'm writing a user app against.  The user app needs to take a firmware image and split it into chunks suitable for sending to the embedded system for programming.  I'm starting with S-record files, and using Xmodem for file transfer (meaning each major 'file' transfer would need to be ended with an EOF), so the easiest thing for me to do would be to split the image file into a set files of full s-records no greater than the size of the receive buffer of the (single threaded) embedded system.  My user app is written in python, and I have a C program that will split the firmware image into properly sized files, but I thought there may be a more 'pythonic' way of going about this, perhaps by using a custom stream handler.

Any thoughts?

Edit : to add to the discussion, I can feed my input file into a buffer.  How could I use range to set a hard limit going into the buffer of either the file size, or a full S-record line ('S' delimited ASCII text)?

Comment: Could be that I don't fully understand your question. By why not just open(filename, 'rb').read() into a buffer (<- list of bytes ...) then just use range() to generate some indexes to slice your buffer, slap an EOF on and send it to the device?

Comment: Blubber ... It's not you that doesn't understand.  I'm a C guy in a python world at the moment and the full faculties aren't always readily apparent to me.... My Xmodem send method takes a file stream as the input, can I use a buffer in that way?

Comment: Oh, ok. I haven't the slightest clue as to what a S-delimited file is, but what you should be able to do is read the whole file into a list (like my other comment), then use slicing (e.g. l[1:10]) to pick a range of bites, but them into a StringIO object (import cStringIO then cStringIO.StringIO(your buffer)), this gives you a string that behaves like a file. Hand that over the xmodem function. Not sure if this is going to work since I have no experience with what you are trying to do, this is the best I can come up with :).

Comment: So it is the slice operation that is unclear.  The file is a set of strings that are "S-records", which is a way of representing binary images in ascii.  Each line can be a different length, but all begin with a small header that starts with 'S', the type of record, and then a line counter.  I need to split my file on these boundaries, which are not a set length.  Sending half of an S-record would be just as bad as overflowing my receive buffer.  How can I use slice to get a full record at a time, while keeping the buffer at a maximum size?

Comment: You can open the file and iterate over it's lines if that helps. In fact, if you open() a file for reading you get an iterator over it's lines (e.g. for line in open(yourfile): do something with line).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought this was an interesting question and the S-record format isn't too complicated, so I wrote an S-record encoder that appears to work from my limited testing.

```
import struct

def s_record_encode(fileobj, recordtype, address, buflen):
    """S-Record encode bytes from file.

    fileobj      file-like object to read data (if any)
    recordtype   'S0' to 'S9'
    address      integer address
    buflen       maximum output buffer size
    """
    # S-type to (address_len, has_data)
    record_address_bytes = {
        'S0':(2, True), 'S1':(2, True), 'S2':(3, True), 'S3':(4, True),
        'S5':(2, False), 'S7':(4, False), 'S8':(3, False), 'S9':(2, False)
    }

    # params for this record type
    address_len, has_data = record_address_bytes[recordtype]

    # big-endian address as string, trimmed to length
    address = struct.pack('>L', address)[-address_len:]

    # read data up to 255 bytes minus address and checksum len
    if has_data:
        data = fileobj.read(0xff - len(address) - 1)
        if not data:
            return '', 0
    else:
        data = ''

    # byte count is address + data + checksum
    count = len(address) + len(data) + 1
    count = struct.pack('B', count)

    # checksum count + address + data
    checksummed_record = count + address + data
    checksum = struct.pack('B', sum(ord(d) for d in checksummed_record) & 0xff ^ 0xff)

    # glue record type to hex encoded buffer
    record = recordtype + (checksummed_record + checksum).encode('hex').upper()

    # return buffer and how much data we read from the file
    return record, len(data)



def s_record_test():
    from cStringIO import StringIO

    # from an example, this should encode to given string
    fake_file = StringIO("\x0A\x0A\x0D\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00")
    encode_to = "S1137AF00A0A0D0000000000000000000000000061"
    fake_file.seek(0)
    record, buflen = s_record_encode(fake_file, 'S1', 0x7af0, 80)
    print 'record', record
    print 'encode_to', encode_to
    assert record == encode_to

    fake_file = StringIO()
    for i in xrange(1000):
        fake_file.write(struct.pack('>L', i))
    fake_file.seek(0)

    address = 0

    while True:
        buf, datalen = s_record_encode(fake_file, 'S2', address, 100)
        if not buf:
            break
        print address, datalen, buf
        address += datalen
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a C program then you're in luck.  Python is like a scripting language over C with most of the same functions.  See [Core tools for working with streams](http://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html) for all the familiar C I/O functions.  Then you can make your program more Pythonic by rolling methods into [Classes](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html) and using things like [The Python Slice Notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/the-python-slice-notation).